# source: not found error while running shell script on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: django, bash, cron, sh, ubuntu-14.04

OS- Ubuntu 14.04

This is my shell script which i want to schedule using cron job.

parser.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

source .profile
workon venv
cd /home/ashish/deployments/myproject

export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myproject.settings_production
python /home/ashish/deployments/myproject/myproject/manage.py parse_data
```

Cron job-

```
*/15 * * * * . /home/ashish/parser.sh
```

Whenever this cron job runs i receive a mail with errors:

```
/bin/sh: 6: /home/ashish/parser.sh: source: not found
/bin/sh: 7: /home/ashish/parser.sh: workon: not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ashish/deployments/myproject/myproject/manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

When i run this script from terminal -

```
. parser.sh    #this gives no error

sh parser.sh   #this gives errors
/bin/sh: 6: /home/ashish/parser.sh: source: not found
/bin/sh: 7: /home/ashish/parser.sh: workon: not found
```

What can be the possible error in this script ?

Comment: Crossposting: http://askubuntu.com/questions/617665/error-while-cron-scheduling-a-sh-script

Comment: sorry i was not aware that cross posting is not permitted.should i remove one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run it with:

```
bash parser.sh
```

not `sh parser.sh`.

If your script is written for `bash`, you shouldn't try to execute it with `sh`. Every syntax of your script may not meet the standards of `sh` Bourne shell.

Change the cron job command to:

```
*/15 * * * * bash /home/ashish/parser.sh
```

to specify `bash` exclusively.
Or as your OS is Ubuntu 14.04, you generally don't need to specify bash, i.e

```
*/15 * * * * /home/ashish/parser.sh
```

should work just fine.

Comment: when i run `bash parser.sh`  on terminal , it halts for a second and then nothing happens.

Comment: Does your script print output on the screen or  do things silently?

Comment: changed `source .profile` to `source /home/ashish/.profile` and  `*/15 * * * * . /home/ashish/parser.sh` to `*/15 * * * * /home/ashish/parser.sh` . Now its working fine! Thanks a lot @jahid